How do I prevent phone from entering 3g mode?
I recently learned how entities can use tech to force phones to switch to 3g networks.
Is there an option in to keep my phone in 4G mode?
AB question, is there a way to ensure that a phone is connected to a real tower and not a middle man?

What version of iOS and which carrier?

@bmike all of them any carrier. but if I had to pick the latest OSX with any carrier.

iOS 18.1 was latest I’ve seen, but 18.2 just dropped and I don’t see anything change from my answer

You can’t do either of the things you ask in the US since there’s no easy way to change broadband settings and carriers here are not incentivized to crack down on non real towers.

Indeed. One compliment: I like Apple products (mostly). One constructive suggestion: I don't like Apple making decisions that could harm their customers (for whatever reason - "it's simple" no it's vulnerable)
